# Windows 10 IoT Raspberry Pi 2: Autostart published Application

Tags: iot, raspberry-pi2, windows-10

I'm starting making experience with the Raspberry Pi 2 Development with Windows 10 and I was wondering how can I configurate the Raspberry Pi 2 to autostart my own published application, I developed in Visual Studio? And furthermore: How can I set up time & Region on my device?

Thank you so much for all helpfull and well meant answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking at how to do this myself this evening. What I found was that you can edit the Pi's startup through Powershell on your PC and tell it what app to load.

*Setting startup app:

Use the startup editor to configure startup apps on your Windows IoT Core device. Run Startup with any of the following options:


Startup /d displays the list of startup apps.


Startup /a [name] [path] adds an app with name name located at path path to the list of startup tasks.


Startup /r [name] removes an app with name name from the list of startup tasks.


For further help, try startup.exe /?*

http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/tools/CommandLineUtils.htm

As far as region settings, you can do that while loading up the default screen on the Pi. When you get to the Windows screen, there is a gear icon in the lower right that will bring you there. Unfortunately, there isn't a real time clock built into the Raspberry Pi, so you'd have to add one (hardware) or pull it from the internet.

Comment: thank you so much, sounds great, I will try this maybe today or tomorrow! Can I have just one Startup-App? Ah thanks, so I have to connect a mouse and Keyboard to the Pi to get to this Screen, I will try this today or tomorrow as well, thank you!

Comment: Just for adding maybe interesting Content, this link provides a similar way to do that: http://ms-iot.github.io/content/win10/samples/HelloWorld.htm (found it right now by searching another Things)

Comment: You can add and remove as many or as little number of apps you want.

Answer (score 6):

Use IotStartup.exe by Power shell.

1. IotStartup list -> Find out your app name.
2. IotStartup add [YourApp]  -> Add App init startup.
3. Reboot.

Answer (score 5):

Something to be warned about.

At the current version, by default Visual Studio generates a random package name for your application, **regardless your Project Name**. My project's name was HelloWorld but it generated a totally different package name.

The name is a random guid and it is being deployed by that name. You can change that name at Project Properties screen. In this example the package name goes as 7e3bb987-a1b9-4a67-9750492af7c7.

[image: Project Properties]

When I remotely connect and run iotstartup list I see that my package is there with that guid name.

[image]

I spent some time to find which app is mine, so I wanted to give heads up to others who might encounter the same. Just rename your Package Name to whatever you want and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The world's easiest way to accomplish this is the following order:

1. open your browser
2. Go to > http://your_RPI2_IP:8080/AppXManager.htm
3. deploy your App from Visual Studio 2015 [with configurations as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzdcD.png)
   3.1 to get this screen go to: project --> Properties --> Right click --> Open
   4 after succesfull deployment select your startup app in the webManager and your RPI2 restarts