# Windows IOT: Deployment on RaspberryPi2 gets ignored

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2, iot

Straight forward question, altough I didn't find anything so far:
I installed all the needed Components and downloaded the examples for Windows IoT C# and Raspberry Pi 2.
I can easily connect and debug at the Raspberry, but if I only want to deploy, kind of nothing happens. I use the Guide for deployment here: https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/AppDeployment.htm#csharp

Also on the Raspberry Pi2, nothing seems to have happened. My Visual Studio Output is like the following:

> 1>------ Deploy started: Project: BlinkyWebService, Configuration:
>   Release ARM ------ 1>Creating a new clean layout... 1>Copying files:
>   Total <1 mb to layout... 1>Checking whether required frameworks are 
>   installed... 1>Registering the application to run from layout...
>   1>Deployment complete (10237ms). Full package name:
>   "BlinkyWebService_1.0.0.0_arm__1w720vyc4ccym"    ========== Build: 0
>   succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

(I kindahow can't format it better?)

Comment: This question appears to belong on [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you try to run the App2App WebServer sample application.

The example contains two separate Solutions. You have to deploy and start both of them. 
The HttpServer project starts a new HTTP Service on port 8000 on the raspberry pi. To Access the demo you have to navigate to http://IpOfTheRasperry:8000 with your web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I meant it more generally: If I deploy an Universal App with one Form, Id expect it to get started directly, but just nothing happens. Also there is no Selection or such possivle on the Raspberry GUI

Comment: From the output you posted I assume that you only deployed the application to the raspberry pi. If you configure visual studio to debug the application on the remote device it should start automatically. 
If you then want to autostart the application on reboot you can try this link [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30040440/windows-10-iot-raspberry-pi-2-autostart-published-application this is something I haven’t tested yet.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. Btw: What else could I do with an App on the Rasperry than directly starting? I can't see any possibility to start it via an Menu or Command-Line on the Rasperry?

Comment: I think, I'll re-as my question the Raspberry Pi 2 board.